# ¿Cómo incluyo archivos .vue a mi proyecto desde un .js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo la siguiente estructura :

> ```
> +assets
> |+js
> | | |+component
> | | | |-componente.vue   
> | | | |-cabecera.vue
> | | |app.js
> +view
>   | |index.html
> ```

En mi archivo index.html incluí esto y funciona.

```
<script src="../assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

Pero mi archivo app.js quiero incluir mis componentes para poder utilizarlos en el index.html

```
let buscadorSKU = require('component/cabecera.vue');
```

El error en consola es en esa linea:

> app.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at app.js:4

Comment: Creo que estas mezclando server con client. En cliente, no hay `require()`. eso es propio de Nodejs. Si quieres usarlo en cliente has de usar la libreria 
 [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). Un saludo

Comment: Por qué estás incluyendo un componente de vue de esa forma? donde definis tu app.vue?

Comment: Lo agrego en el archivo app.js. Creo que vivo algo confundido con esto de agregar los documentos en vue.